# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 50 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
use cdss_prod
--
--select top 5 datedifF(second, dt_created_by, dt_updated_by),* from t_queue where cd_case_type=1 and nm_queue_type=1 order by 2 desc
--select top 50 datedifF(second, dt_created_by, dt_updated_by),* from t_queue where cd_case_type=2 and nm_queue_type=1 order by 2 desc
--select top 5 * from t_alert where cd_source_app='39211' order by 1 desc


--

--retrieve speed of QueueProcessing
DECLARE @startDt datetime, @endDT datetime;
SET @startDT = DATEADD(minute,+60, '2015-09-01 00:00') --'2015-05-14 15:45:35.047'-- '2015-05-14 15:20:00.000' 
SET @endDT =  DATEADD(minute,-0, '2015-12-31 23:59'); --'2015-05-14 15:55:35.047'-- '2015-05-14 15:40:00.000'
select @startDT,@endDT,timeDiff,CaseType,QueueType,count(id_queue)
from 
(
SELECT (CASE    
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '0' THEN '00 - 01' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '1' THEN '01 - 02' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '2' THEN '02 - 03' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '3' THEN '03 - 04' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '4' THEN '04 - 05' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '5' THEN '05 - 06' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '6' THEN '06 - 07' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '7' THEN '07 - 08' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '8' THEN '08 - 09'
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '9' THEN '09 - 10' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '10' THEN '10 - 11' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '11' THEN '11 - 12' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '12' THEN '12 - 13' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '13' THEN '13 - 14' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '14' THEN '14 - 15'  
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '15' THEN '15 - 16' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '16' THEN '16 - 17' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '17' THEN '17 - 18' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '18' THEN '18 - 19' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '19' THEN '19 - 20' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '20' THEN '20 - 21'
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '21' THEN '21 - 22' 
            WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '22' THEN '22 - 23' 
            ELSE '23 - 00' 
        END
        ) AS timeDiff
            , id_queue, (CASE nm_queue_type WHEN 1 THEN 'Med Queue' ELSE 'Lab Queue' END) AS QueueType 
            , (CASE cd_case_type WHEN 1 THEN 'eIMR' WHEN 2 THEN 'eRX' ELSE 'DRx' END) AS CaseType 
    FROM t_queue WHERE nm_del_flag=1 
                                        AND NM_FLAG_PROCESS>0
                                        AND (dt_created_by between @startDT AND @endDT) AND nm_queue_type=1 and cd_case_type in (1)
) 
GROUP BY timeDiff,CaseType,QueueType ORDER BY queuetype DESC, casetype desc, timediff DESC


select count(*) as totalERxCount from t_queue with (nolock) 
    where (dt_created_by between @startDT and @endDT) and nm_queue_type=1 and cd_case_type=1
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below one , with table alias

```
 select @startDT,@endDT,timeDiff,CaseType,QueueType,count(id_queue)
    from 
    (
    SELECT (CASE    
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '0' THEN '00 - 01' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '1' THEN '01 - 02' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '2' THEN '02 - 03' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '3' THEN '03 - 04' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '4' THEN '04 - 05' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '5' THEN '05 - 06' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '6' THEN '06 - 07' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '7' THEN '07 - 08' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '8' THEN '08 - 09'
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '9' THEN '09 - 10' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '10' THEN '10 - 11' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '11' THEN '11 - 12' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '12' THEN '12 - 13' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '13' THEN '13 - 14' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '14' THEN '14 - 15'  
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '15' THEN '15 - 16' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '16' THEN '16 - 17' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '17' THEN '17 - 18' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '18' THEN '18 - 19' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '19' THEN '19 - 20' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '20' THEN '20 - 21'
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '21' THEN '21 - 22' 
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, dt_created_by) = '22' THEN '22 - 23' 
                ELSE '23 - 00' 
            END
            ) AS timeDiff
                , id_queue, (CASE nm_queue_type WHEN 1 THEN 'Med Queue' ELSE 'Lab Queue' END) AS QueueType 
                , (CASE cd_case_type WHEN 1 THEN 'eIMR' WHEN 2 THEN 'eRX' ELSE 'DRx' END) AS CaseType 
        FROM t_queue WHERE nm_del_flag=1 
                                            AND NM_FLAG_PROCESS>0
                                            AND (dt_created_by between @startDT AND @endDT) AND nm_queue_type=1 and cd_case_type in (1)
    ) AliaseTable
    GROUP BY timeDiff,CaseType,QueueType ORDER BY queuetype DESC, casetype desc, timediff DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need specify alias in FROM clause

```
...
) as data
GROUP BY ...
...
```